# Filebrowser showing IOError while uploading files(images,docs etc.......)

Tags: file-upload, content-management-system, django-templates

In django CMS project...i used filebrowser for file uploading .But Filebrowser showing IOError while uploading files in django python 1.4.1.
 Anyone who solved this one ,please answer or give me any solution.
While uploading images or documents using filebrowser the image/document is uploaded but always showing error....

Comment: Please add more informations. Just a guess: missing write permissions?